# Como puedo cambiar el formato de 24 hrs a 12hrs, al llamar información de SQL desde PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Como puedo cambiar el formato de 24hrs a 12 hrs al momento de llamar mi tabla? los datos los ingreso como tipo TIME y en SQL los guardo en varchar. Al momento de mostrar tienen el formato de 24hrs. Ya cambie el tipo varchar por tipo time en SQL pero se mantiene el 24hrs.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿MySQL?, si el campo tiene horas, entonces usa [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format). Por ejemplo: `TIME_FORMAT(la_columna, '%r') AS cualquier_alias`. Ver, [formatos disponibles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Gracias bro, me sirvió, ya solo modifique un poco el formato para que me mandara horas, minutos y ya sea am o pm. `TIME_FORMAT(hora_inicio,'%l%:%i%p') AS hora_inicio`